# Pybabel generates empty pot file with jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-babel

I'm using Flask, Flask-Babel and Jinja2. I'm trying to generate the .pot file. That what I did so far.

**My babel.cfg looks like this:**

```
[python: **.py]

[jinja2: **.html]
encoding = utf-8
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

**I'm initialize Flask-Babel with my app like this:**

```
# Babel init
babel = Babel(app)
app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = 'en'
```

**In my templates directory I do have homepage.html:**

```
...
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <p class="quote">{{ gettext('Hey there') }}</p>
    <p class="quote">{% trans %}Trying 42{% endtrans %}</p>
    <p class="quote">{{ _('Maybe like this?') }}</p>
</div>
...
```

**Then running this command(while I'm in my virtualenv):**

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .
```

**One of the outputs lines is:**

```
extracting messages from templates/homepage.html (extensions="jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_", encoding="utf-8")
```

**And it is generates a messages.pot file with this content:**

```
# Translations template for PROJECT.
# Copyright (C) 2015 ORGANIZATION
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PROJECT project.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, 2015.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: EMAIL@ADDRESS\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-04-21 10:06+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: Babel 1.3\n"
```

The file does not have my translations.

I get no errors or warnings, pybabel just can't find the `gettext` variations in jinja2 files. **BUT** when I use the `gettext` in  a .py file **it is** working just fine.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending hours to figure it out I found the solution, posting for future help if someone will need it.

I had Flask-Assets installed in my templates, apparently if you have it, you need to add in you `babel.cfg`:

```
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_,webassets.ext.jinja2.AssetsExtension
```

From the Flask-Assets docs:

> Otherwise, babel will not extract strings from any templates that include an assets tag.

I'm going to do a pull request that checks if you have Flask-Assets and Flask-Babel installed and you didn't added the right extension, It will give you warning - I think the developer should get some error/warning.

Comment: Setting `silent=False` in your `babel.cfg` will help pinpoint the problem: thing is, this should really be the default :(

Thanks for pointing out the webassets Jinja2 extension!

Comment: Phew, this was an obscure bug -- thank you for posting your fix, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same problem and in my case the issue was specifying input files, i.e. files where to look for strings marked for translation.

When I run `pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot` as suggested in various tutorials (for example [this one](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/11/27/flask-internationalization-and-localization/)) I got `pybabel: error: no input files or directories specified` error.

The command that finally worked for me was:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot --input-dirs=.
```

Answer (score 5):

For others who may not be using the Assets Extension as referred in the accepted answer, the problem could lie with the `babel.cfg` file itself.

For me the problem was with my `babel.cfg` file which I had taken from this [tutorial](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/11/27/flask-internationalization-and-localization/).

Later when I switched to using the babel.cfg file right from the question here, things worked out nicely for me.

Just for record, here is the `babel.cfg` file which worked for me.

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **.html]
encoding = utf-8
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem:

input:

`pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k _l -o messages.pot`

output:

`Usage: pybabel extract [options] <input-paths>`

`pybabel: error: no input files or directories specified`

My solution is just to add **two spaces and a period** after input command.

`pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k _l -o messages.pot  .`

Hope this helps.

Update:

My `babel.cfg` file is:

`[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **.html]
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_`